# Book about about a powerful alien civilisation visiting Earth, aliens refuse to give Earth helpful technology

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Sometime between 1982 and 1984, I borrowed a book from the school library, which was about a powerful alien civilisation visiting Earth. Humanity asked for medicines and technology to help with its problems. Instead, the aliens ask for their help and take a group to a primitive planet to solve a problem. The humans realise that their technology would affect the planet badly - the aliens then explain that's why they can't help humanity.

I have the impression that the book may have been written sometime before the eighties.

Comment: :) Can we get you to go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if the suggestions there help elicit more details?